# PHP FileToUpload Undefined Index error

Tags: php, linux

I want to upload a file to `uploads`, but I get this error message everytime:

> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in /path/to/dir/upload.php on line 3

**HTML File:**

```
<form action="php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow.

You have to move line 3 to be included in the if statement, because if there was no post, the global `$_FILES` variable will not be set.

eg:

```
<?php
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

And even then, there might not have been a a file posted

So :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"], $_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
```

Comment: Get the next Error: 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: what do your logs say ?

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error 
only this..

Answer (score 0):

"fileToUpload" is not available at initial load.

try this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$uploadOk = 1;
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Get the next Error: 500 - Internal Server Error